# strtotime conversion with variable error

Tags: php, date, timestamp, strtotime

I am getting wrong output i.e. `1194908400`
None of this is working i.e. I tried to put double quotes around variable, tried without quotation marks. result is same and wrong.

```
$d='07-11-13';
echo $d;
echo strtotime($d);
echo "<br>";
echo strtotime("$d");
```

Comment: Isn't strtotime supposed to receive "YYYY-MM-DD"? like $d="2013-11-07"...

Comment: what output do you want?

Comment: @briosheje `strtotime` can accept many different formats: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php  I believe you're on to the issue though, the function is confusing the month and day

Comment: strotime("2013-11-07") outputs 1383778800 which is correct. You should check http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php . Ps: strtotime("07-11-13") outputs 131194908400 to me, which is not correct, if I'm not going wrong :P

Comment: You need to put in 07-11-2013, that should give you the right time. It's getting confused because it can't work out what format you are using, whether you are using dd-mm-y or y-mm-dd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you need to specify a 4 digit year, so that strtime can fully work out which date format you are using. With `07-11-13` it probably thinks you are using `2007-11-13`.

Change it to `07-11-2013` and you will get the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

After a few checks, the error is actually NOT in the format you're passing, but rather on the way you're passing it.

What you should do is just replace "13" with "2013":

```
strtotime("07-11-2013");
```

output: 1383778800

```
echo strtotime("2013-11-07");
```

output: 1383778800

```
echo strtotime('07-11-13');
```

output: 1194908400

Answer (score 0):

$d='07-11-13' is wrong, Try this

```
$d='2013-11-13';
echo $d;
echo strtotime($d);
echo "<br>";
echo strtotime("$d")
```

Answer (score 0):

strtotime() will accept:

```
m/d/y
d-m-y
```

With / it expects month/day and with - it expects day-month.